# JSON parsing in its own separate function is not working

Tags: ios, json, parsing, swift3

All the tutorials that I have seen or read about Swift 3 JSON parsing include placing JSON parsing code inside `viewDidLoad()` func/method and it works great. I want to place JSON parsing code in its own function and call it from `viewDidLoad()`. Check below example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var ArrayImages = [String]();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var json = ParseJson();
        print("My Array = \(ArrayImages)");

    }

    // NEW FUNCTION
    func ParseJson() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://etasawoq.com/go_categories.php")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if (error != nil){
                print("Error Found Creating URLSession : \(error)")
            } else {
                if let ParsedJson = data {
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: ParsedJson, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray

                        for x in json {
                            let row = x as! NSDictionary; 
                            let imageUrl = row["image_url"] as! String
                            self.ArrayImages.append(imageUrl);
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Json Processing failed \(error)");
                    }
                }
            }
        }.resume() // start session
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the "ArrayImages" is not being populated when calling the `ParseJson` function. The print output is "My Array = []". Why is that? How can I solve this problem while keeping JSON parsing code in a separate function?

Comment: Your `ParseJson`method is making async call, so it is execute in background so that  `print("My Array = \(ArrayImages)");` is executed before completion block of `dataTask(with:)`

Comment: Your code would have the exact same issue even if it was all in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Then how this problem can be solved? image i want to populate a tableView with actors name. How can i achieve that using my current style of code?

Comment: @Aboodnet For that just reload your Tableview `tableview.reloadData()` after for loop.

Comment: @NiravD Assuming there is table view involved, make sure that call is done on the main queue.

Comment: @rmaddy You are right i'm just saying is for that you just need to reload your `tableView`, also it is batter if you use swift native Dictionary and Array instead of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response getting through block so you need to print array in side the block not outside  as below .

```
do {

                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: ParsedJson, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray

                        for x in json {
                            let row = x as! NSDictionary; 
                            let imageUrl = row["image_url"] as! String
                            self.ArrayImages.append(imageUrl);
                        }
                      print("My Array = \(ArrayImages)");
                    }
```

Comment: I tried that before and i know it works this way but later on i want to perform some actions in viewDidLoad() like updaing a label or even populating a collectionView for images. Your way will not work because as soon as the .resume() being hit, the array will be empty again.

Comment: yes but in every way you face this problem . but what you want to do after you got response .

Comment: Lets say populating a tableView with actors names from json url

Comment: it is the last sucess callback so you can do populate your tableview here.try once with this answer.